# Conversion from one base to another

Tags: java

I already try to make a program it works as well but the problem is, that is not the same output what i want.

Note **

That is what i want..

**enter starting base:**   it should be binary or octal or hexa

**enter end base:**        it should be decimal

**enter number:**     if 2 is entered as the starting base only 1s and 0s can be entered. If  16 is entered as the starting base 0-9 and A-F can be used.

and what i make :(

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a starting base: ");
String binaryNumber = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter a end base: ");
String octalNumber = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
String decimalNumber = scanner.nextLine();
int myInt = Integer.parseInt(binaryNumber, 2);
int myInt2 = Integer.parseInt(octalNumber, 8);
int x = myInt;
System.out.println(
     binaryNumber + " in Binary, is "
   + Integer.toString(myInt, 8) + " in Octal" + " and "
   + Integer.toString(x, 10)  +" in decimal");
```

Comment: myInt2 and x are never used, why?

Comment: Please don't tag your question with three different languages if your question is only about one of them.

Comment: @user2475627 see my answer for demo

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do. Figure out the code and understand. You have `Scanner#nextInt()` method to read integers. You don't have to use `nextLine()` method for this. And more over, `Scanner#nextInt(int radix)` accepts the input in specified radix form. It throws an exception if you don't enter the input in that form. You can catch that exception to display the error message to the user.

Your goals  `startBase`,`endBase`, and the variables used for them `binaryNumber` is mismatching. Please name your variables which convey the purpose of them.

See the modified version of your code here:

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Tester{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a starting base: ");
        int startBase = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a end base: ");
        int endBase = scanner.nextInt();
        int number=0;
       try{
          System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
          number= scanner.nextInt(startBase);
          System.out.println("Entered number:"+number+"(base"+startBase+")");
          System.out.println("Converted number:"+Integer.toString(number,endBase)+"(enbase"+endBase+")");

       }catch(InputMismatchException e){
              System.out.println("Invalid input for the given radix");
              e.printStackTrace();   //you can comment it if you don't need this.
       } 
      }
  }
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply.   enter starting base: it should be binary or octal or hexa

enter end base: it should be decimal

enter number: if 2 is entered as the starting base only 1s and 0s can be entered. If 16 is entered as the starting base 0-9 and A-F can be used.

Comment: @user2475627 see you can't restrict what user enters into the console but you can only issue error messages if he enters wrongly.... if you want the input number based on the starting base he entered, you may give a message before entering the actual number..... :) what's your actual exercise.....if possible add the exercise text into the question... if you want the conversion based on ending base you can just use the variable end base as the second parameter in the `Integer.toString` method in your `println` statement...